# Termux can't run shell script

Tags: android, shell-script, termux

As stated in the topic above, I am trying to configure a hardware using shell script which is downloaded from the official website of Orange Pi. Am using termux as the medium to run the shell script of the config file. But, whenever I try running the shell script, it shows permission denied. The shell script needs a rooted hardware. I have rooted the Orange Pi. I am running the shell script in 'su' state. Still it shows permission is denied. Any suggestion?

I have run: './script.sh' and 'sudo ./script.sh' Both of the command above is run in 'su' state

both of it shows permission is denied. Any suggestion on how should I do it?

have checked on the permission of the config file. the config file have permission of read and write. so, it is a non-executable file.

I have also run command 'chmod +x' to configure the config file to an executable config file. but, after running the command, there's nothing change to the permissions of the config file. still have the permission for read and write. executable permission is not added. why?

Comment: `executable permission is not added.` Probably because your script is in the emulated SD card (e.g. `/sdcard/Download/`) instead of the data directory of Termux (e.g. `HOME`, i.e., `/data/data/com.termux/files/home`).

Comment: my script is in a directory /storage/self/primary. Do I need to change the directory to enable the permission of executable?

Comment: `/storage/self/primary` is basically the same thing as `/sdcard` (there's also `/storage/emulated/0`). And yes, you'll need to move the script to somewhere under the Termux app data directory as I mentioned to be able to set the executable bit(s). However, you can probably do something like `bash /sdcard/Download/some_script.sh` as well. (Use whichever shell that the script is written for.)

Comment: have tried changing the directory, still facing the same issue. also have tried command 'chmod u+x script.sh' and also 'chmod ug+x script.sh'. nothings change

Comment: The fact that you keep saying "change directory" makes me wonder what exactly you did / mean by that. Please update your question with the actual current full path of the script. (For example, if you have `cd`ed to where the script is, run `realpath script_name.sh` and share the output.) Besides, it would be best if you can share the full output of what you run to execute the script and the full output you get.

Comment: it's ok sir. I've already found the solution for the problem faced. Before, I am downloading the linux code from external and transfer it to the board. The solution is to download the linux code directly from the board. thank you for the information given.